# Find pattern and replace PLUS operation?

Tags: csv, vim, notepad++, delimiter

<del>Is this possible in regex?</del> Suppose I got these entries:

`1005,15,0,0,0
1014,20,0,0,0
1084,3,360000,180000,1
1025,5,0,0,0`

what I am supposed to have is, find a number that has comma before it & exactly `,0,0,0` and after that, replace the number with 140% of its number

`1005,15*1.4,0,0,0
1014,20*1.4,0,0,0
1084,3,360000,180000,1
1025,1*1.4,0,0,0`

if it has decimal point, round it up 1, and remove the decimal point, so that:

`1025,1,0,0,0` => `1025,2,0,0,0`

the final should be, something like:

`1005,21,0,0,0
1014,28,0,0,0
1084,3,360000,180000,1
1025,2,0,0,0`

Can somebody please lead me to proper regex find and replace?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Figured out Regex can't do this, so any tool that can help me with this?

Comment: perhaps now is the right time to know a better editor, like vim. with vim, the task could be easily done. btw, the last line should be `5*1.4` not `1*1.4` right?

Comment: oh yes, you're right, haven't slept for a very long time, forgot the math, hence 1 would still remain 1. Downloading vim for windows now, so how can this be done on vim?

Comment: if you add vim tag, I would post an answer with vim. a single command will do.

Comment: @Kent sorry, yes. Actually, spending the time knowing what "vim tag" means. LOL.

Comment: The tag of the question. like csv ,notepad++ ,delimiter...

Comment: @Kent And, I'd been searching for some time to what vim tag means. btw, how do you open files via VIM on windows? when I open vim, it is already a blank text? and when I drag drop something, it seems to be having trouble with forward slashes?

Comment: see my answer, I added a gif for showing how vim works. You need read some tutorial to know what vim is. google vim, you can get a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first of all, I don't have windows system. To open file with vim, I guess it should be same as `vim foo.file`?

anyway, back to your question, the command is:

```
:%s/\d\+\ze,0,0,0$/\=float2nr(ceil(submatch(0)*1.4))/
```

it works like:

[image]

Note that I added a new line to show how ceil() worked.

If this is your first time open vim, you need read some tutorials. If you have experience with vim, you can check following help details for the cmd above:

```
:h :s
:h \ze
:h ceil(
:h submatch(
:h float2nr(
```

Comment: voted as answer since it seems to be the easiest way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a perl one liner that does the job:

```
perl -p -i.back -e "s/,(\d+)((?:,0){3})/','.(1.4*$1).$2/e"  foo.txt
```

This will replace, as wanted, each number that is preceeded by `,` and followed by `,0,0,0` by this number multiplied by `1.4`.

The original file is saved in filename.back before replacing the values.

**edit:**
If you want want to round the result (ie. no decimals) you could do:

```
perl -p -i.back -e "s/,(\d+)((?:,0){3})/','.sprintf('%d',(1.4*$1)).$2/e"  foo.txt
```

Comment: does it also round the number, and remove the decimal? Sorry, have no idea with Perl, but will try, will download it now.